# Input Field onchange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field in apex given below

```
<apex:inputField value="{!paymentDetails.Amount__c}" onChange="enableLppAmount(this)" required="true" />
```

Also I have a simple input box

```
<input type="number" id="lppAmount" disabled="true"/>
```

I have the following javascript

```
function enableLppAmount(input){
    if(input.value.length > 0){
    document.getElementById("lppAmount").disabled=false;
    }
    else {
     document.getElementById("lppAmount").disabled=false;
    }
    }
```

Now When i enter any number in the apex input it is not enabling the html input. Basically the function is not being called. I want that when someone enters value in the apex input the simple input should be enabled and if no value then disabled. 
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have forget to apply semi coloun after calling javascript method

```
<apex:inputField value="{!paymentDetails.Amount__c}" onChange="enableLppAmount(this);" required="true" />
```

also script must be in

```
<script> function enableLppAmount(input){
    if(input.value.length > 0){
    alert(hi);
    document.getElementById("lppAmount").disabled=false;
    }
    else {
     document.getElementById("lppAmount").disabled=false;
    }
    }
</script>
```

tags

Comment: Also I had a problem which I was facing that above apex input field I had a button to add a row from the controller for the same record so that user can enter multiple amounts . The onchange works only on the first row amount inout field not on the other rows why is that so?

Comment: I feel this is not right answer. There is no such requirement to add semi colon post function call in java-script.

Comment: It worked for me

Comment: Yes but with code given in question/answer it can never work. See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the reasons why code was not working:

```
alert(hi);
```

This statement will treat 'hi' as a javascript variable and will try to find out 'hi' variable. As there is no 'hi' variable in code it will throw error and rest of the function will not work properly.
Another problem:

```
 document.getElementById("lppAmount").disabled=false;
```

Same statement is written in `if` and `else` blocks. So Same behavior will be experienced for every change in input value.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out that was actually a typo error I had put them inisde the "" brackets initially. I have removed them from the question though